# Time Travel Debugging: how to install it without the store?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

I've a problem on a preproduction server and I thought it was the right time to try the time travel debugger added to the WinDbg Preview.
But it seems impossible to get it outside a dev machine:

- Install only available from the store ... so need to be connected on the store
- Windows 10 requirements

Is this features usable outside the development environment ? If yes, how ?
Thank you

Comment: afaik only store and iirc andy luhrs from windbg team was proposing some msix but i think it never materialized in the war to collect telemetry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If you target OS is Windows Server 2016, 2019 or Windows 10,** you can use the standalone reduced features version of TTD, now present in most recent versions of Windows. For now, the only thing you can do with this standalone version that comes with the OS is to attach to an existing process to record the trace. This is the command syntax:

**Requires elevated privileges**

```
TTTracer [-out <folder-name-for-run-file>] -attach <PID>
```

Example:

[image: sample tttracer]

After reproducing the problem, run from another command prompt to stop capturing:

```
TTTracer -stop all
```

Example:

[image: tttracer stop]

Answer (score 6):

Open this [website](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) and type in the url for the [Windbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) and click on checkmark to generate the links to the appx files.

[image],

now download the appx and install it with the [App Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/app-installer/9nblggh4nns1) or extract it with Unzipping Tool like 7zip and run it on older Windows like Windows 7/8.1.

[image]

Comment: this is third party isnt it? i mean it might be suitable for hobbyists but not for working place isnt it

Comment: what is the point? it generates links to official Microsoft server. I use it very often when store says "currently unavailable"

Comment: I've tried your workaround and can indeed download the appx from MS server. But I don't know if I would be allowed to install it on the server as it not an official package

Comment: @Fabske how is it not an "official package"? It comes directly from Microsoft!

Comment: @fabske yes be explicit ask and get permission before installing it if you are going to use it on an unowned official machine  there is too much telemetry flowing out if these apps

Comment: btw you can get the links using invoke web-request -uri rd-adg....../getfiles. -body storeurl (from share link in apps download page in ms site the 9xxx) -outfile foo.html and wget the appx and extract to a folder in usb with 7zip

Comment: @IanKemp it's not official because 1/ no direct link on microsoft website 2/ no announced compatibility with Windows Server. But don't get me wrong, you gave a real/usable alternative

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "not an official package". It is the same package that the store installs

Comment: Yes, but you can't install store package on server and compatibility is still only w10 (Try to explain your solution to a security guy in a big company and you'll understand my pain :D). But indeed I made an error the answer comes from you so you gave a real workaround that I'm trying to use.

Comment: ok, I haven't tried server , extract the appx with 7zip and run DbgX.Shell.exe, look if this works on server, as you see in picture this works on 8.1

Comment: @Fabske: if you have a portable app, you just bring it on your USB stick. There is 1) no Microsoft download as well 2) no announced compatibility as well. Just run it and you're good. IDK if it runs on Server OS. Try it before you go to the customer, if you doubt it. Why shouldn't it run? WinDbg 10 also ran on Windows 7 except some special commands. IMHO SysAdmins will like the fact that they don't need to install anything and reboot the machine.

Comment: @ThomasWeller no way to bring a USB stick and connect it to the server :). But I'll try this tool